# How to find the dimension of the kernel

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Definine $f: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}: x\longmapsto 1$, $g: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}: x\longmapsto x$ and $h: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}: x\longmapsto e^{x}$. Let $V$ be the vectorspace $vct \left\{f, g, h\right\}$. Next define the linear transformation $D: V\to V$:
$\ D(k)=ak+bk'+k'' \
$for every  $k\in V$ and with $a, b\in \mathbb{R}$

Give $\dim \ker(D)$ in function of $a$ and $b$.

I think this is the matrix from the linear transformation.
$$\
    \left[
        \begin{matrix}
            a &  \phantom{-} ax& ae^x  \\
            0 &              b& be^x  \\
            0 &  \phantom{-}0 & e^x 
        \end{matrix}
    \right]
$$

I don't know how to simplify this further and eventually to find the kernel.

(Sorry for the bad coding of the matrix)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have that $D(k) $ is a function for every function $k\in V$, then $D(f) (x) =af(x) +0+0=af(x)$, $D(g) (x) =ax+b=ag(x) +bf(x) $ and $D(h)(x) =(a+b+1) e^x=(a+b+1) h(x) $, so your matrix is $\begin {pmatrix} a&b&0\\ 0&a&0\\0&0&a+b+1\end{pmatrix}$. Do you know how to end?

Comment: I have found that the dim = 1 with (0, 0, (a+b+1)µ), is this correct?

Comment: Ehm.. I think there are more cases... Just think that if $a\ne 0$ and $b\ne -1-a$ your matrix is invertible, so kernel is 0.

Comment: Ah yes I think I was approaching this wrong. I just set the matrix equal to the zero matrix. But I'm still a bit confused. For example what's the kernel when a=0 and b=1?

Comment: Oh, no, you can study the rank for instance with the strategy of minors.

Comment: So I don't know if you saw the edit on my previous comment but what do you get when a=0, b=1 or vice versa? And my first comment with  (0, 0, (a+b+1)µ) that was correct?

Comment: If $a=0$ and $b=1$ you obtain a matrix with the second and the third columns indipendents, and with first column 0, so the dimension of kernel is 1 since the rank is 2 and for example the vector $(1,0,0)$ generates the kernel.

Comment: You helped me out so much, thank you for your time!